# Updating an Enum for a ScriptableObject based on another enum selection?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, unity-editor

Basically, I am creating a `ScriptableObject Skill` and I want to restrict it to only certain character types. However, I can't quite figure out how to go about doing it. I want to avoid having a single enum for all the classes unless it is unavoidable. I will try and show you what I mean below.

```
public class Skills : ScriptableObject {

public string Description;
public Sprite Thumbnail;
public int LevelNeeded;
public int XPNeeded;

ClassRestrictions classRestrictions;

}

public enum ClassRestrictions
{ None, Warrior, Rogue, Mage };
```

If in the editor I select `Warrior` I would want another enum to appear and ask about if I want to restrict it to a certain subtype. Something like this:

```
public enum WarriorSubClassRestrictions
{None, Barbarian, Knight, Paladin};
```

However, if I selected the Rogue type I wouldn't want the Warrior Enum to appear. Is there a way to do this in the Editor inside of my ScriptableObject class?

Comment: So you wish to use an enum to check which class a character has, so that you can use this to make certain information appear, is that correct?

Comment: @Doh09 Yes that is correct

Comment: Provided 2 options that I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm. The only way I can think of doing this is something along these lines:

```
public interface IClassRestriction<T> {
    public T subclass { get; set; }
}

public class ClassRestrictionWarrior : IClassRestriction<WarriorSubClassRestrictions>{
    public enum WarriorSubClassRestrictions {
        None, Barbarian, Knight, Paladin
    }
}
```

By declaring the `subclass` property as a generic and defining that generic by the implementation, that should work.

Answer (score 1):

---

**If you wish to use a solution without enums**, you can have a scriptable object per class that then has a list of scriptable object subtypes.

```
public class CharacterClass : ScriptableObject{
    List<CharacterClassSubType> SubTypes; //Holds the list of all subtypes available to this class.
    CharacterClassSubType SelectedSubType; //The subtype chosen.
}

public class CharacterClassSubType : ScriptableObject{
    //Subtype code
}
```

The same thing would work for placing skills into them.

---

**If you wish to use enums**

You can use an if statement or a switch to check which enum is selected.

Then in each of the checks where you run the code you have a specific code set shown.

**If statement**

```
if (classRestrictions == ClassRestrictions.Knight)
{
//Class is a knight, run your code here to show subclasses for the knight.
}
```

**Switch statement**

```
switch(classRestrictions )
{
     case ClassRestrictions.Barbarian:
     //Run Barbariancode to show relevant subclasses.
     break;
     case ClassRestrictions.Knight:
     //Run knight code to show relevant subclasses.
     break;
     case ClassRestrictions.Paladin:
     //Run Paladincode to show relevant subclasses.
     break;
     case ClassRestrictions.None:
     //Run Nonecode to show relevant subclasses.
     break;
     case default:
     //Run default code, chosen if none of the others apply.
     break;
}
```

If something isn't clear please don't hesitate to ask.